# opencv make error cmath ‘::cos’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I'm trying to install opencv on ubuntu. so far I have downloaded opencv 3.1 and done this:

```
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..
```

but when I try to make it, by using `make` it shows these kind of errors:

> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:63:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
>    __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (*Mdouble* __x));

or

> /usr/include/c++/5/cmath:199:11: error: ‘::cos’ has not been declared

and so on. what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Is it a problem when building *your* code? Or building OpenCV?

Comment: it's with building OpenCV. I'm trying to install OpenCV on ubuntu 16.04